# How to print plain html in bluetooth thermal printer in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, thermal-printer

I can print String in bluetooth thermal printer like this:

```
try {
            // the text typed by the user
            Spanned spanned;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                spanned = Html.fromHtml(
                        " <h1>My first styled page</h1>" +
                                "<p>Welcome to my styled page!</p>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
            } else {
                spanned = Html.fromHtml(
                        " <h1>My first styled page</h1>" +
                                "<p>Welcome to my styled page!</p>");
            }
            String msg = spanned.toString();
            msg+="\n";
            msg+="\n";
            mmOutputStream.write(msg.getBytes());
            Log.i(TAG, "sendData: Data sent.");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

but printer is not printing like the expected HTML format, its just printing plain text, though `<h1><p>` is not being printed but they don't print in the expected size either. How can I print a spanned text more specifically how can I convert a HTML formatted string into bytearray?

Comment: I would recommend using the following library to print text of all formats:
https://github.com/DantSu/ESCPOS-ThermalPrinter-Android

This has got a decent documentation and support for wide range of Thermal printers